# Duplicate component ID found in view

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am getting an error like **Component ID component has already been found in the view** inside tree table **column tag with id=col1**. I have two Managed Beans for this single xhtml file and both are session scoped.

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Category and Brand Manage Page</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="/templates/layout.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">              
            <h:form id="productform" enctype="multipart/form-data" rendered="#{loginManagedBean.isLoggedIn}">
                <p:growl id="messages" autoUpdate="true" redisplay="false" showDetail="true"/>

                <p:panel header="Brand Management" id="brandpanel">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellspacing="20">

                        <p:outputLabel value="Branch Name"/>
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="branchname" value="#{brandManagedBean.branchId}" style="width: 200px;">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Branch" itemValue=""/>
                            <f:selectItems value="#{brandManagedBean.branchNamesMap}"/>
                               <p:ajax listener="#{brandManagedBean.selectBrands()}" update="brandpanel"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>

                        <p:outputLabel value="Brand Name"/>
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="brandname" value="#{brandManagedBean.id}" style="width: 200px;">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Brands" itemValue=""/>
                            <f:selectItems value="#{brandManagedBean.brandNamesMap}"/>
                            <p:ajax event="change"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>

                        <p:outputLabel value="New or update brand name"/>
                        <p:inputText value="#{brandManagedBean.name}">
                            <p:ajax event="change"/>
                        </p:inputText>  
                    </h:panelGrid>
                    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                        <p:commandButton update="brandpanel" actionListener="#{brandManagedBean.insertBrand()}" value="Add"/>
                        <p:commandButton update="brandpanel" actionListener="#{brandManagedBean.updateBrand()}" value="Update"/>
                        <p:commandButton update="brandpanel" actionListener="#{brandManagedBean.deleteBrand()}" value="Delete"/>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:panel>

                <p:panel header="Category Management" id="categorypanel">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellspacing="20">

                        <p:outputLabel value="Branch Name"/>
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="categorybranchname" value="#{categoryManagedBean.branchId}" style="width: 200px;">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Branch" itemValue=""/>
                            <f:selectItems value="#{categoryManagedBean.branchNamesMap}"/>
                            <p:ajax listener="#{categoryManagedBean.selectFloors()}" update="categorypanel"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>

                        <p:outputLabel value="Floor Name"/>
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="categoryfloorname" value="#{categoryManagedBean.floorId}" style="width: 200px;">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Floor" itemValue=""/>
                            <f:selectItems value="#{categoryManagedBean.floorsMap}"/>
                            <p:ajax listener="#{categoryManagedBean.selectCategories()}" update="categorypanel"/>
                            <p:ajax listener="#{categoryManagedBean.loadTreeTable()}" update="categorytree"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </h:panelGrid>  

                    <h:panelGrid columns="4">
                        <p:outputLabel value="Category Name"/>
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="categoryname" value="#{categoryManagedBean.catId}" style="width: 200px;">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Category" itemValue=""/>
                            <f:selectItems value="#{categoryManagedBean.categoryMap}"/>
                            <p:ajax listener="#{categoryManagedBean.selectSubCategory1()}" update="categorypanel"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>                              

                        <p:outputLabel value="New Category Name"/>
                        <p:inputText value="#{categoryManagedBean.catName}">
                            <p:ajax event="change"/>
                        </p:inputText> 
                    </h:panelGrid>

                    <h:panelGrid columns="4">
                        <p:outputLabel value="Item Name"/>
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="subcategoryname" value="#{categoryManagedBean.subcat1Id}" style="width: 200px;">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Item" itemValue=""/>
                            <f:selectItems value="#{categoryManagedBean.subCategory1Map}"/>
                            <p:ajax event="change"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>

                        <p:outputLabel value="New Item Name"/>
                        <p:inputText value="#{categoryManagedBean.subcat1Name}">
                            <p:ajax event="change"/>
                        </p:inputText> 
                    </h:panelGrid>

                    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                        <p:commandButton update="categorypanel" actionListener="#{categoryManagedBean.insertCategory()}" value="Add"/>    
                    </h:panelGrid>                    

                    <p:treeTable id="categorytree" value="#{categoryManagedBean.root}" var="catdto"
                                 selectionMode="single" selection="#{categoryManagedBean.selectNode}">

                        <f:facet id="face1" name="header">
                            Categories
                        </f:facet>

                        <p:column id="col1">
                            <f:facet name="header" id="face2">
                                Category Name
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputLabel id="out1" value="#{catdto.name}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column id="col2">
                           <f:facet name="header" id="face3">
                               Edit
                           </f:facet>
                            <p:commandLink id="com1" update=":productform:documentPanel" oncomplete="PF('documentDialog').show()" title="Update Form" styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil"  >
                               <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{catdto}" target="#{categoryManagedBean.selectedCategoryDto}" />
                           </p:commandLink>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column id="col3">  
                           <f:facet name="header" id="face4">
                               Delete
                           </f:facet>
                            <p:commandLink id="com2" action="#{categoryManagedBean.deleteCategory(category)}" type="button"                          
                                style="float: right; background-image: url('../resources/images/delete.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat;
                                background-size: 100% 100%; background-origin : border-box; width: 30px; height: 20px;">          
                           </p:commandLink>                               
                        </p:column>
                    </p:treeTable> 

                </p:panel>
                    <p:dialog id="dialog" header="Update Form" showEffect="fade" widgetVar="documentDialog" modal="false" maximizable="true" minimizable="true">  
                        <p:outputPanel id="documentPanel">  
                            <h:panelGrid  columns="2" cellpadding="5">  
                                <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Category: " /> 
                                <p:inplace id="basic">
                                    <h:inputText id="name" value="#{categoryManagedBean.selectedCategoryDto.name}" style="font-weight:bold" />  
                                </p:inplace>                               

                                <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-left: 100px">
                                    <p:commandButton action="#{categoryManagedBean.updateCategory()}" value="Update" ajax="false" update=":categorypanel"/>                      
                                    <p:commandButton action="#{categoryManagedBean.clear}" value="Clear" id="btnclear" ajax="false" />
                                </h:panelGrid>  
                            </h:panelGrid>  
                        </p:outputPanel>  
                    </p:dialog>                         

            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**Stack Trace**

```
SEVERE: JSF1007: Duplicate component ID productform:categorytree:col1 found in view.
Dec 12, 2013 5:27:01 PM com.sun.faces.util.Util checkIdUniqueness
SEVERE: +id: j_id1
type: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot@9ce387
+id: javax_faces_location_HEAD
 type: com.sun.faces.component.ComponentResourceContainer@1f54217
+id: j_id2
 type: javax.faces.component.UIOutput@c5f91c
+id: j_id3
 type: javax.faces.component.UIOutput@165c08a
+id: j_id4
 type: javax.faces.component.UIOutput@143b527
+id: j_id5
 type: javax.faces.component.UIOutput@2a237a
+id: j_id6
 type: javax.faces.component.UIOutput@7f29f4
+id: j_id7
 type: javax.faces.component.UIOutput@9b66f1
+id: j_id8
 type: javax.faces.component.UIOutput@837332
+id: j_id9
 type: javax.faces.component.UIOutput@1fffbc8
+id: j_idt1
type: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


+id: j_idt2
 type: javax.faces.component.UIOutput@1ddf77
+id: j_idt3
 type: 
            <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
            <title>Madharsha Control Panel Page</title>

  +id: j_idt4
  type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlBody@14ba6a4
   +id: j_idt5
   type: org.primefaces.component.layout.Layout@1a96d23
   +id: header
   type: org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnit@3c41cb
    +id: j_idt6
     type: org.primefaces.component.outputlabel.OutputLabel@39137
     +id: j_idt7
      type: org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnit@32e320
      +id: layoutform
      type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm@dd4f1b
       +id: rootmenu
       type: org.primefaces.component.menubar.Menubar@1747f49
        +id: homemenu
         type: org.primefaces.component.menuitem.UIMenuItem@150d2fe
        +id: mastermenu
         type: org.primefaces.component.submenu.UISubmenu@14c3f17
          +id: j_idt8
           type: org.primefaces.component.menuitem.UIMenuItem@c23503
          +id: j_idt9
           type: org.primefaces.component.menuitem.UIMenuItem@265e80
        +id: tabletmenu
         type: org.primefaces.component.menuitem.UIMenuItem@1063704
        +id: logoutmenu
         type: org.primefaces.component.menuitem.UIMenuItem@105ea2f
        +id: loginmenu
         type: org.primefaces.component.menuitem.UIMenuItem@151e258
      +id: productform
      type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm@e33152
       +id: messages
       type: org.primefaces.component.growl.Growl@1bb22d9
       +id: brandpanel
       type: org.primefaces.component.panel.Panel@ed0cd7
        +id: j_idt10
         type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlPanelGrid@e60409
          +id: j_idt11
           type: org.primefaces.component.outputlabel.OutputLabel@11325cd
          +id: branchname
           type: org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenu@16e471
            +id: j_idt12
             type: javax.faces.component.UISelectItem@efdaaa
            +id: j_idt13
             type: javax.faces.component.UISelectItems@fcd37b
          +id: j_idt14
           type: org.primefaces.component.outputlabel.OutputLabel@a04e7e
          +id: brandname
           type: org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenu@814915
            +id: j_idt15
             type: javax.faces.component.UISelectItem@1e52afd
            +id: j_idt16
             type: javax.faces.component.UISelectItems@697520
          +id: j_idt17
           type: org.primefaces.component.outputlabel.OutputLabel@1888b29
          +id: j_idt18
           type: org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputText@1686d07
        +id: j_idt19
         type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlPanelGrid@ce1366
          +id: j_idt20
           type: org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButton@15b920e
          +id: j_idt21
           type: org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButton@d1de09
          +id: j_idt22
           type: org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButton@482a86
       +id: categorypanel
       type: org.primefaces.component.panel.Panel@1dfcbc3
        +id: j_idt23
         type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlPanelGrid@1baa99d
          +id: j_idt24
           type: org.primefaces.component.outputlabel.OutputLabel@1d590a3
          +id: categorybranchname
           type: org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenu@afcd9
            +id: j_idt25
             type: javax.faces.component.UISelectItem@15e0b9b
            +id: j_idt26
             type: javax.faces.component.UISelectItems@14bfd33
          +id: j_idt27
           type: org.primefaces.component.outputlabel.OutputLabel@1dc4c0b
          +id: categoryfloorname
           type: org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenu@485e7
            +id: j_idt28
             type: javax.faces.component.UISelectItem@f326a7
            +id: j_idt29
             type: javax.faces.component.UISelectItems@16ed6d9
        +id: j_idt30
         type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlPanelGrid@1db4fa7
          +id: j_idt31
           type: org.primefaces.component.outputlabel.OutputLabel@14a8a00
          +id: categoryname
           type: org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenu@aa4749
            +id: j_idt32
             type: javax.faces.component.UISelectItem@12e467c
            +id: j_idt33
             type: javax.faces.component.UISelectItems@11589f6
          +id: j_idt34
           type: org.primefaces.component.outputlabel.OutputLabel@1147608
          +id: j_idt35
           type: org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputText@511e57
        +id: j_idt36
         type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlPanelGrid@19eef40
          +id: j_idt37
           type: org.primefaces.component.outputlabel.OutputLabel@16d756e
          +id: subcategoryname
           type: org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenu@138c603
            +id: j_idt38
             type: javax.faces.component.UISelectItem@50093a
            +id: j_idt39
             type: javax.faces.component.UISelectItems@8dea14
          +id: j_idt40
           type: org.primefaces.component.outputlabel.OutputLabel@102f163
          +id: j_idt41
           type: org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputText@35cd5d
        +id: j_idt42
         type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlPanelGrid@3dc0e2
          +id: j_idt43
           type: org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButton@4269de
        +id: categorytree
         type: org.primefaces.component.treetable.TreeTable@349f31
          +id: j_idt44
           type: 
                            Categories

          +id: col1  <===============
           type: org.primefaces.component.column.Column@eb38b5
            +id: out1
             type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputLabel@d802ee
          +id: col2
           type: org.primefaces.component.column.Column@1a88afb
            +id: com1
             type: org.primefaces.component.commandlink.CommandLink@3c7600
          +id: col3
           type: org.primefaces.component.column.Column@1671af2
            +id: com2
             type: org.primefaces.component.commandlink.CommandLink@1a2769
          +id: col1  <===============
           type: org.primefaces.component.column.Column@bf5e96
            +id: j_idt45
             type: 
                                Category Name

            +id: out1
             type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputLabel@2e2067
          +id: col2
           type: org.primefaces.component.column.Column@51703d
            +id: j_idt46
             type: 
                               Edit

            +id: com1
             type: org.primefaces.component.commandlink.CommandLink@9fc24a
          +id: col3
           type: org.primefaces.component.column.Column@8cb5ba
            +id: j_idt47
             type: 
                               Delete

            +id: com2
             type: org.primefaces.component.commandlink.CommandLink@1eef7db
      +id: dialog
       type: org.primefaces.component.dialog.Dialog@1d26686
        +id: documentPanel
         type: org.primefaces.component.outputpanel.OutputPanel@491682
          +id: j_idt48
           type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlPanelGrid@64db02
            +id: j_idt49
             type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputLabel@1667f48
            +id: basic
             type: org.primefaces.component.inplace.Inplace@2e50af
              +id: name
               type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText@b34ab2
            +id: j_idt50
             type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlPanelGrid@ed25ec
              +id: j_idt51
               type: org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButton@154ae8e
              +id: btnclear
               type: org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButton@90196c
      +id: footer
      type: org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnit@753f4a
      +id: j_idt52
     type: org.primefaces.component.outputlabel.OutputLabel@18e3248
   +id: j_idt53
     type: 
     </html>

   Dec 12, 2013 5:27:01 PM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
      SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/product/productmanage.xhtml]
      java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component ID productform:categorytree:col1 has already been found in the view.  
at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:974)
at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:958)
at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:958)
at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:958)
at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:958)
at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:958)
at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:958)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletFullStateManagementStrategy.saveView(FaceletFullStateManagementStrategy.java:706)
at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.saveView(StateManagerImpl.java:89)
at javax.faces.application.StateManager.getViewState(StateManager.java:593)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.renderState(PartialViewContextImpl.java:454)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:322)
at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:57)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1004)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1896)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:425)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2430)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2419)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: You are definitely mixing the needed scopes. That view should lie in a `@ViewScoped` bean. If you need the values into other view, just pass it as parameters or keep **only what you need** at `@SessionScoped`. Related to the problem, if you provide me an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) with code I can copy-paste-run, I'll be grateful to make some tests. What jsf primefaces implementation-versions are you using?

Comment: Primefaces 4.0 and JSF 2.2, How do I give you the code?

Comment: @XtremeBiker I am getting the error when I give **<p:ajax listener="#{categoryManagedBean.selectFloors()}" />** ajax tag but this is necessary to load next panelgrid.

Comment: @XtremeBiker I solved the error. I don't know why Jsf needs all the treenodes to be initialized inside bean's constructor. I Initialized all treenodes with empty string value and then everything works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the error. I don't know why Jsf needs all the treenodes to be initialized inside bean's constructor. I Initialized all treenodes with empty string value and then everything works fine. It works in both **Session/View Scoped** beans.

**UPDATE: 1**
This error may also occur because of incorrect ajax updations. I was trying to make ajax request from each component and updating the whole panel(Components where inside a panel). Then I changed the updations to update only specific view Eg. SelectOneMenu. Solution here is update only specific components without updating the whole form or view.

**UPDDATE: 2**
I changed in web.xml file param-value from false to true, then this problem is solved,

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Glad to see it. It's probably related with components lifecycle. However can't see it without the related managed bean.

Comment: I had a similar problem when moving to JSF 2.2, which I too fixed by removing the PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING context-param altogether. I previously had it set to false to enable the workaround discussed here: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same problem. javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING can only by 'true' or 'false' and cannot be 'server'. Removing the param or initialize it with an invalid value cause that the default value will be used (which is true).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by setting saving state method to "server" instead of "client":

```
<context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
```