# p:dialog not hidden in html and directly rendered on page

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, xhtml

I have a `p:dialog`, which is usually not rendered on the page and when I activate it, it is shown as a popup in a new window.

```
<p:dialog id="dialogAdressvalidierung"
              header="Adresse auswählen"
              widgetVar="popupAdrValidierung"
              modal="true"
              draggable="true"
              showEffect=""
              hideEffect=""
              width="900"
              resizable="false"
              appendTo="@(body)">
    <!--dialogs content-->
</p:dialog>
```

The html output usually is something like this

```
<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-hidden-container ui-draggable"
     id="dialogAdressvalidierung"
     role="dialog"
     aria-hidden="true"
     aria-labelledby="dialogAdressvalidierung_title"
     style="width: 900px; height: auto;">
     <!--content-->
</div>
```

In one case however, I need to refresh the page on the server.

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Application application = context.getApplication();
ViewHandler viewHandler = application.getViewHandler();
UIViewRoot viewRoot = viewHandler.createView(context, context.getViewRoot().getViewId());
context.setViewRoot(viewRoot);
context.renderResponse();
```

After executing the java code above, all the dialogs in the xhtml files are displayed inside the html and the page looks awfully distorted. Some attributes like `aria-hidden="true"` and `role="dialog"` of the `div` elements, that result from the `p:dialog` are gone:

```
<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-hidden-container"
     id="dialogAdressvalidierung">
    <!--content-->
</div>
```

Why is the html output of the p:dialog not hidden anymore? How do I get the dialogs to not be shown on the page and still only popup when activated?

Comment: Why are you refreshing the page fron the server in the way you do it?

Comment: Because if I don't, jsf generates duplicate ids, like discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20543070/duplicate-component-id-found-in-view and no solution given there helps in my case.

Comment: The link you post only mentions the 'duplicate id' error caused in this case by  duplicate ajax updates. There are several other posts about duplicate id's all with different causes. So instead of trying to fix something caused by the workaournd, fix the original issue. You are effectively now running into a http://xyproblem.info. And for next questions/comments, please read http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive (I did not downvote yet)

Comment: Oh I wasn't aware, that there duplicate id issues with so many different causes. Thanks for the information. I didn't realize the page refresh was a workaround, because it is so deeply written into the program I am working on, that it is called frequently from many parts of the program. So I thought it was just the way to work with jsf. So the issue described in the question seems to be a different one than I thought. Not sure what to do with this thread now...